# Expected end ASP error

Tags: html, asp-classic, ado

I am not sure how to fix the following error:

```
Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a03f6'

Expected 'End'

/junk/test.asp, line 103

else
^
```

Relevant code:

```
      <%
    con.MoveNext()
    Wend
      %>
  </table>


  <% else %>

  <p>No seminars available.</p>

  <%
  end if
  con.close
  %>
```

Whole code:

```
<%@ LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" %>

<%
        Dim connectString, connect, conDB, con, src_st
        connectString = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("data")
        src_st = Request.QueryString("state")
        set connect = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
        connect.open connectString
        if src_cat = "" then
        conDB = "SELECT * FROM travel.csv"  
        else
        conDB = "SELECT * FROM travel.csv where state = ' & src_st & '" 

        set con = connect.execute(conDB)
%>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<title>Seminars &amp; workshops - AvSafety Seminars</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/style/screen.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/style/avsafety.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="handheld" href="/style/handheld.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="/style/print.css" />

<meta name="MSSmartTagsPreventParsing" content="true" />


<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style2 {color: #666666 }
-->
</style>

<!--

-->


</head>
<body>

<div id="printtitle">Civil Aviation Safety Authority</div>
<div id="outer_wrapper">
<div id="wrapper"> 
<div id="container"> 
<div id="title"><h1>&nbsp;</h1></div>



      <img src="images/windsock.jpg" alt="" width="166" height="500" align="right" />
<div id="content"> 

<!--Start of main content area-->

<div id="right"> <img src="/wcmswr/_assets/main/seminars/images/AVSAFETY-LOGO.GIF" alt="AVSafety logo" border="0" width="250px" height="50px">


</div>
      <h1>AvSafety Seminars</h1>

<p>CASA is  continuing with the Safety Seminar program, targeting pilots in regional Australia and run in partnership with the local aviation industry. </p>
<p>We also hold seminars targeted at engineers.</p>
<p><a href="/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD::pc=PC_100841">View further information on safety issues and topics</a>.</p>

<h2>Request a seminar</h2>
<p> If you would like to request an AvSafety seminar in your local town, use the <a href="/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD::pc=PC_100683">AvSafety request from</a>.</p>

<h2>2013 Seminar schedule</h2>

<p>In 2013 CASA ASAs will be focusing on visiting organisations to discuss the forthcoming aviation regulatory changes. They will be in all regions of Australia and individuals or organisations are welcome to contact their local region ASA to arrange an appointment time. The approximate travel schedule for each region is shown below. ASAs are available and active each month for visits within capital city environs (approximately within 2 hours driving of a capital city).</p>
<p>Aero clubs and other aviation organisation are welcome to run Aviation Safety Seminars with ASAs presenting topics, however CASA will not be financially supporting the events. If you would like to run a seminar with ASA attendance, please use the <a href="/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD::pc=PC_100683">AvSafety request from</a> and complete the details of the request. Every effort will be made to provide support however it will be advantageous to consider timings when an ASA is visiting a local region.
</p>

<p><a href="avsafety?src_st=ACT">ACT</a> | <a href="avsafety?src_st=NSW">NSW</a> | <a href="avsafety?src_st=ACT">QLD</a> | <a href="avsafety?src_st=ACT">SA</a> | <a href="avsafety?src_st=ACT">TAS</a> | <a href ="avsafety?src_st=ACT">VIC</a> | <a href="#">WA</a></p>

   <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>

 <% while (NOT con.EOF) %>

    <tr>
        <td><%=con("location")%></td>
        <td><%=con("state")%></td>
        <td><%=con("date")%></td>
    </tr>

      <%
    con.MoveNext()
    Wend
      %>
  </table>


  <% else %>

  <p>No seminars available.</p>

  <%
  end if
  con.close
  %>

<!--End of main content area-->
</div> <!-- content -->
</div> <!-- container -->

<div id="sidebar">
<h2 id = "sidebarhome"><a href="/index.htm">CASA home</a></h2>
<h2><a href="/seminars/index.htm">Seminars &amp; workshops</a></h2>
<ul>

<li><a href="/seminars/avsafety.asp">AvSafety Seminars</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="/seminars/eng.htm">Maintenance seminars</a></li>
    <li><a href="/seminars/archerfield.htm">Archerfield chief pilots</a></li>
<li><a href="/seminars/cbt/index.htm">Competency Based Training Education</a></li>
<li><a href="/seminars/manufacturing.htm">Manufacturing & certification workshop</a></li>
</ul>

<form action="http://agencysearch.australia.gov.au/search/search.cgi" name="agencysearch"> 
<input type="text" name="query" size="13" maxlength="50" value="" alt="Search field" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="collection" value="agencies" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="form" value="simple" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="profile" value="casa" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Search" name="Search" alt="Search button" /> 
</form>

</div>

<div class="clearing">&nbsp;</div>
</div><!-- wrapper -->
</div> <!-- outer_wrapper -->

 <div class="extras"> 
<a href="/tools/contacts.asp">Contact CASA</a> 
</div>

<div class="footer"> 
<a href="/tools/siteinfo.htm">Site&nbsp;help</a>&nbsp; |&nbsp;
<a href="/tools/cpyright.htm">Copyright </a>&nbsp; |&nbsp; <a href="/tools/privacy/index.htm">Privacy</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no `if` before that else as far as I can see.

Comment: If I remove else i get "Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'

Object required: ''

/junk/test.asp, line 109"

Comment: The construct is `if..else..endif`. So either keep all 3, or remove the `else` and the `endif`.

Comment: You need to use "end if" while you are connecting to database. And there is no start of "if" before while loop

Comment: After removing the else and end if, I get "Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a03f6'

Expected 'End'

/junk/test.asp, line 98" .. it keeps repeating..

Comment: Which is line 98? Indicate that as well.

Comment: 96-98 is:   <%
    con.MoveNext()
    Wend
   %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what if you change your code to this ?

```
<%
        Dim connectString, connect, conDB, con, src_st
        connectString = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("data")
        src_st = Request.QueryString("state")
        set connect = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
        connect.open connectString
        if src_cat = "" then
        conDB = "SELECT * FROM travel.csv"  
        else
        conDB = "SELECT * FROM travel.csv where state = '" & src_st & "'"   
        end if

        set con = connect.execute(conDB)
%>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<title>Seminars &amp; workshops - AvSafety Seminars</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/style/screen.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/style/avsafety.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="handheld" href="/style/handheld.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="/style/print.css" />

<meta name="MSSmartTagsPreventParsing" content="true" />


<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style2 {color: #666666 }
-->
</style>

<!--

-->


</head>
<body>

<div id="printtitle">Civil Aviation Safety Authority</div>
<div id="outer_wrapper">
<div id="wrapper"> 
<div id="container"> 
<div id="title"><h1>&nbsp;</h1></div>



      <img src="images/windsock.jpg" alt="" width="166" height="500" align="right" />
<div id="content"> 

<!--Start of main content area-->

<div id="right"> <img src="/wcmswr/_assets/main/seminars/images/AVSAFETY-LOGO.GIF" alt="AVSafety logo" border="0" width="250px" height="50px">


</div>
      <h1>AvSafety Seminars</h1>

<p>CASA is  continuing with the Safety Seminar program, targeting pilots in regional Australia and run in partnership with the local aviation industry. </p>
<p>We also hold seminars targeted at engineers.</p>
<p><a href="/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD::pc=PC_100841">View further information on safety issues and topics</a>.</p>

<h2>Request a seminar</h2>
<p> If you would like to request an AvSafety seminar in your local town, use the <a href="/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD::pc=PC_100683">AvSafety request from</a>.</p>

<h2>2013 Seminar schedule</h2>

<p>In 2013 CASA ASAs will be focusing on visiting organisations to discuss the forthcoming aviation regulatory changes. They will be in all regions of Australia and individuals or organisations are welcome to contact their local region ASA to arrange an appointment time. The approximate travel schedule for each region is shown below. ASAs are available and active each month for visits within capital city environs (approximately within 2 hours driving of a capital city).</p>
<p>Aero clubs and other aviation organisation are welcome to run Aviation Safety Seminars with ASAs presenting topics, however CASA will not be financially supporting the events. If you would like to run a seminar with ASA attendance, please use the <a href="/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD::pc=PC_100683">AvSafety request from</a> and complete the details of the request. Every effort will be made to provide support however it will be advantageous to consider timings when an ASA is visiting a local region.
</p>

<p><a href="avsafety?src_st=ACT">ACT</a> | <a href="avsafety?src_st=NSW">NSW</a> | <a href="avsafety?src_st=ACT">QLD</a> | <a href="avsafety?src_st=ACT">SA</a> | <a href="avsafety?src_st=ACT">TAS</a> | <a href ="avsafety?src_st=ACT">VIC</a> | <a href="#">WA</a></p>

   <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>

 <%
if NOT con.eof then
 while (NOT con.EOF) %>

    <tr>
        <td><%=con("location")%></td>
        <td><%=con("state")%></td>
        <td><%=con("date")%></td>
    </tr>

      <%
    con.MoveNext()
    Wend
      %>
  </table>


  <% else %>

  <p>No seminars available.</p>

  <%
  end if
  con.close
  %>

<!--End of main content area-->
</div> <!-- content -->
</div> <!-- container -->

<div id="sidebar">
<h2 id = "sidebarhome"><a href="/index.htm">CASA home</a></h2>
<h2><a href="/seminars/index.htm">Seminars &amp; workshops</a></h2>
<ul>

<li><a href="/seminars/avsafety.asp">AvSafety Seminars</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="/seminars/eng.htm">Maintenance seminars</a></li>
    <li><a href="/seminars/archerfield.htm">Archerfield chief pilots</a></li>
<li><a href="/seminars/cbt/index.htm">Competency Based Training Education</a></li>
<li><a href="/seminars/manufacturing.htm">Manufacturing & certification workshop</a></li>
</ul>

<form action="http://agencysearch.australia.gov.au/search/search.cgi" name="agencysearch"> 
<input type="text" name="query" size="13" maxlength="50" value="" alt="Search field" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="collection" value="agencies" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="form" value="simple" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="profile" value="casa" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Search" name="Search" alt="Search button" /> 
</form>

</div>

<div class="clearing">&nbsp;</div>
</div><!-- wrapper -->
</div> <!-- outer_wrapper -->

 <div class="extras"> 
<a href="/tools/contacts.asp">Contact CASA</a> 
</div>

<div class="footer"> 
<a href="/tools/siteinfo.htm">Site&nbsp;help</a>&nbsp; |&nbsp;
<a href="/tools/cpyright.htm">Copyright </a>&nbsp; |&nbsp; <a href="/tools/privacy/index.htm">Privacy</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That works. I still don't understand why it wasn't working though.

Comment: @sephiith you were missing an end if  and i just added a check for an empty recordset